# Should I use "Daydream technical preview" version of Unity to develop for Cardboard?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr, daydream, google-vr-sdk

Is it a requirement to use the "Daydream technical preview" version of Unity with Google VR SDK, even if I am targeting Google Cardboard? I don't think this is clear from the documentation, and I don't want a development environment which is Daydream-specific.

Currently, I have installed Unity 5.5.1f1 and Google VR SDK 1.20. However, in player settings, I do not get any of the Cardboard/Daydream options shown in this screenshot:

[image]

https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/get-started#prerequisites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a requirement to use the "Daydream technical preview" version of
>   Unity with Google VR SDK, even if I am targeting Google Cardboard?

No. If you are building for Daydream  then you need the *Daydream technical preview*. Note that there are some sample scenes from the *Google VR SDK* plugin that are exclusively meant for Daydream. One such example is the VideoDemo. These scenes have Daydream  scripts that won't compile on a normal Unity version. If you use the normal Unity version, you will get compile-time errors if you load one of these scenes.

*Daydream technical preview* is only used to experiment building for Daydream at this moment. It will be added to the normal Unity version when it is ready and with most bug fixed.

In fact, Daydream support is now added to *Unity 5.6 beta*. You can get that [here](https://unity3d.com/unity/beta). I suggest you start developing with Unity 5.6 beta in order to prevent mistakenly using scripts are made for *Unity 5.6 beta*.

Comment: One such sample scene in GVR SDK is the VideoDemo, which only seems to be supported by Daydream.

Comment: I ran into this problem before but just can't remember which one. If you are sure about this, you can edit it into my answer.